# Comparison of classification algorithms: How can I interpret the results?

Tags: svm, random-forest, natural-language, text-mining, naive-bayes

I am experimenting on a dataset of about 18,000 articles, 12000 tagged Fake and 6000 tagged Real.
I'm building a fake news classifier and I'm comparing 4 classification algorithms: Multinomial Naive Bayes, Linear SVM, Logistic regression and Random Forest. 
I'm using two different approaches:
1) content-based: Bag of words with TFIDF 
2) context-based: about 80 numerical features for each article (Sentiment analysis, part of speech, average length of sentences,% of stopwords, etc.)

The results I obtained are the following:
1) In the first case MNB, SVM and LogReg have similar performances (accuracy 91-93%), while Random Forest obtains results lower of  5-6%.

2) In the second case, RF obtains the best results (accuracy: 87%), followed by LogReg (accuracy: 80%), SVM (accuracy: 74%) and MNB (accuracy: 60%).

From a theoretical point of view, how can these results be explained?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Your question is way too broad, and it is unlikely that someone will speculate on why your results are the way they are. Is there a more narrow aspect that interests you?

Comment: I would like to know if there is a well-defined motivation for which SVM, MNB, LogReg, perform better than RF in the bag of words model with TFIDF.
If the answer is too long, bibliographic references are also good.
Thanks so much :)